# Spanish for "file"

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática

I have come across **fichero** and **archivo** although the latter seems more ubiquitous. Is there any difference in usage? Or is it just a matter of personal preference? Also, if **archivo** is *file*, what's the Spanish for the actual *archive* folder as found in many email accounts?

Comment: @aparente teníamos ya la etiqueta [tag:cartas], lo mismo valía con esa sin utilizar [tag:email] y simplemente complementar con [tag:informática].

Comment: @fedorqui - OP está haciendo dos preguntas, y la segunda es *how can I refer to an email archive folder?*  Nota también que ELU tiene 251 preguntas con la etiqueta *email*, y *French Language* tiene 9.  Nuestro sitio no tiene que adoptar la misma estructura de etiquetas que usan esos sitios; lo menciono para mostrar que sería dentro de lo razonable introducir una etiqueta *email*.  ¿Para qué tener etiquetas?  Para ayudar a la gente a encontrar preguntas sobre un tema determinado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Fichero** is more common in Europe (Spain) while **Archivo** is common in Latin America.

I would suggest you use **Archivo**, based on these definitions:

> **Archivo:** A group of well-organized documents managed by a person or enterprise.
>
> **Fichero:** Is a furniture to keep organized documents.

But in IT, both have the same meaning which is a collection of information stored somewhere (devices, memory, etc).

I think Spaniards use **fichero** because in the past they stored their documents in cabinets but for Latin Americans it was not limited to cabinets. It's is also related to the way you organize your documents in a cabinet, binder or folder.

In case of **archive folder** in emails it's a little bit different because for Latin America it is used as an adjective **Archivado** (singular) o **Archivados** (plural). This means to keep your files, documents or emails **away from your current ones** for a later search. The same intention as in English.

Comment: I lately realised answers telling that you can name archive folder as simply Archivos, but I disagree. Archivos is most understood as  Files. Archive in that context is more a state.  That's why Archivados it fits better as translation. Better way too know,  it's changing gmail or any other mail provider from English to Spanish or look up for YouTube videos about Correos Archivados.

Answer (score 4):

As with many computing terms, *fichero* and *archivo* competed against each other for dominance, and at this point it's pretty clear that *archivo* will be the victor.

In computing contexts, you should use *archivo* for *file*.

For archives in the long term, out-of-the-way sense, *archivo* (with its verb *archivar*) are also used. There's not much confusion generated by the overlap of terms especially when you can use the verb form.

For other files (like police/academic/medical), in my experience, the most common term is *expediente*. As *aprendedor* notes, you can also hear *dossier* (with double S per the DRAE), though that can also be used for a report.

Comment: You wrote, "In computing contexts, you should use *archivo* for *file*."  I'm not sure if this would apply for all meanings of *file* in computing contexts.  I thought that if it's a docx file, perhaps I should call it *un documento*?

Comment: @aparente001 a file can contain a document, sure. If I know it's a jpg I could use *imagen" or *foto* but at the hard drive level they're all archivos

Comment: Thanks.  Getting back to MS Word, typically would one call it *documento* or *archivo*?  I don't like ambiguity.  Could I simplify things and use *archivo* for folder, and *documento, imagen,* etc., for *file*?  Also, what about spreadsheets?  Thank you.  I left Mexico before laptops became ubiquitous.

Comment: @aparente001 A folder is a *carpeta* or *directorio* (same difference as in English between folder and directory — no real difference just some people/systems prefer one or the other, or will even freely interchange them).  All files are *archivos*, but any given *archivo* could be a *documento*, *imagen*, *sonido*, etc.  It's like animals vs dog/cat/bird, etc.  If in English I'd say "file" — "Upload your file here", I'd use "archivo", if I'd say "document" — "Please submit your CV as a Word document", I'd go with "documento".

Comment: Got it!  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I work in the IT world and some people use "archivo" and some use "fichero". We understand both terms are used for files

The folder to archive mails is called "archivo", and the real life term used in Spain is "archivo" as well, "fichero" is almost never used besides computer related stuff. As Maximus Decimus says, "fichero" is a furniture, while "archivo" is a concept. I can't really talk about the other spanish speaking countries

Comment: I use both interchangeably. Also, coming from the old school, I use "carpeta" or "directorio" for folder.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, *fichero* and *archivo* are the most commonly used words for file. Sometimes *el dossier* or *el dosier* is used (obviously from the same French word from which "dossier" in English came).

The "archive" folder would just be called, as far as I know, *el archivo (de correo electrónico)*.